# How to use Ajax Update Panel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I used an UpdatePanel to prevent all page reload when clicking a button.  But when I use it the upload file doesn't work and have null filled.  When I removed the update panel it worked well.  So how can I solve this issue?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPAddPost" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset style="width: 498px; text-align: right; padding: 5px; direction: rtl;">
                    <legend>GO</legend>
                    <div class="add-post">
                        <textarea class="textarea" name="" cols="3" rows="3" runat="server" id="txpost"></textarea>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVAddPost" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*"
                            ControlToValidate="txpost" ValidationGroup="AddUserPost">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add-post-control">
                        <div class="post">
                            <asp:Button Text="go" runat="server" ID="btAddPost" OnClick="btAddPost_Click" ValidationGroup="AddUserPost" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                            <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                                <span>
                                    <img src="res/images/img.png" width="38"  height="27" /></span>
                                <input type="file" runat="server" class="upload" id="FUFile" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>


<Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btAddPost" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work due to a restriction on the browser ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715505/231716)).  You have to use the AJAXControlToolkit [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.aspx) control, which was meant to handle this.  You can also use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), or several other utilities (there are controls for this in products like Telerik, etc.)